# Regular expression for string between escape characters

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have  a string and I want to extract substring between escape characters.

e.g.

```
   AC001 (\\Test123\homedir$) (H:)
```

How can i get Test123 in java

Comment: three hints: 1) `.` matches any character 2) with parenthesis `()` you create a new group. The `Matcher` class support to query such groups. 3) To use `.` for any String befor the first escape char and after the second escape char, you should use a non-greedy search. Without non-greedy `.` is eating any character :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
    String input = "AC001 (\\Test123\\homedir$) (H:)";
    String regex="(\\\\.*\\\\)";
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(input);
    while (mtchr.find()) {
        String res=mtchr.group();
        System.out.println(res.substring(1, res.length()-1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex you can do:

```
String str = "AC001 (\\\\Test123\\homedir$) (H:)"; 
String substr = str.substring(str.indexOf('\\')+2, str.indexOf('\\', str.indexOf('\\')+2));
//=> Test123
```

Comment: that's fine until you get: \\Test123\\Test456\\Test789\\homedir$

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "AC001 (\\Test123\homedir$) (H:)";

s = s.substring(s.indexOf('\\') + 2);
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('\\'));

System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*\\\\(.*?)\\h.*", "$1");
```

This regex matches the entire string, but captures the target, which is the returned using a back reference.